# No package s3cmd available

Tags: centos, rpm, s3cmd

I am trying to install an `s3cmd` rpm on my CentOS 6.x by using the command `yum install s3cmd` but I am getting the following error output :

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security 
Setting up Install Process 
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile  
* base: centos.mirror.net.in  
* extras: centos.mirror.net.in  
* updates: centos.mirror.net.in 
No package s3cmd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Can somebody provide me URL from where I could manually download `s3cmd` rpm or any other solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

The [s3tools repos](http://s3tools.org/repo/) are empty now.  Please get it from the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository instead, which I am able to keep maintained.

```
$ sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install s3cmd
```

Comment: This also works for centos7.  Sadly the s3tools project seems to have stopped maintaining repos so they have nothing for centos7 or any other recent updates.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem using following steps :-

> 1. cd /etc/yum.repos.d
> 2. wget http://s3tools.org/repo/RHEL_6/s3tools.repo
> 3. yum install s3cmd

Comment: This worked for me. Allows one to install **s3cmd version 1.0.0** (the older one)

Comment: Much newer versions are available through EPEL which is readily supported by centos.  The s3tools repos seem to be dead since 2014.

Answer (score 1):

You can also download the package from this [url](https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/s/s3cmd-2.0.2-1.el7.noarch.rpm), and then install it manually via command

```
yum localinstall s3cmd-2.0.2-1.el7.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: Your link is dead. I suggest https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/s/s3cmd-2.0.2-1.el7.noarch.rpm

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the answer with your link.